# Stack Postfix Evaluation?

Tags: java, stack

How can i evaluate using stack that counts two operands when the input operator is (+,-,*,/)? for example
Input:
3
4
5
+
Output :
4+5 = 9
Input:
*
Output :
 3*9 = 27
Input:
10
/
Output:
27/10 = 2.7
Input:
1
-
Output: 2.7-1 = 1.7
My problem is that I'm unable to store the input as integers and then evaluating it to produce such output.
my Stack() code

```
public class Stack {

    int maxSize;
    int top;
    String array[];

    public Stack(int n)
    {
        maxSize = n;
        array = new String[maxSize];
        top = 0;
    }

    public boolean empty()
    {
        if(top==0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void push(String str)
    {
        if(top < maxSize)
        {
        array[top] = str;
        top++;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Stack Overflow !!!");
        }
    }

    public String pop()
    {
        if(!this.empty())
        {
            String temp = this.peek();
            array[top-1] = null;
            top--;
            return temp;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String peek()
    {
        if(top > 0) 
        {
        return array[top-1];
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

my main code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();  <-- error?
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Stack myStak = new Stack(3);
        System.out.println("Input : ");


        String input;
    do{
       input = sc.next()+sc.nextLine();
       myStak.push((input));
       String operator = myStak.peek();
        switch(operator.charAt(0))
        {
            case '+':
            int a = Integer.parseInt(myStak.pop());
            int b = Integer.parseInt(myStak.pop());
            int result = a+b;
            myStak.push(Integer.toString(result));
            System.out.print("Output : ");
            System.out.print(a+" + "+b+" = "+result);
                break;
        }
           // myStak.push(myStak.pop() + myStak.pop());
           // System.out.println("Output:");
           // System.out.println(myStak.pop()+"+"+myStak.pop());


    }
    while(input!= "+" || input!= "-" || input!= "*" || input!= "/");
```

Comment: You need to keep in mind two things. 1) when you pop it is no longer on the stack so you should store it in temp variable.  2) when you pop twice keep in mind which is the left hand side and which is the right hand side of the operator.

Comment: I did store it in a temp variable but when I'm inputing an operator such as "+", it is giving me an error, do you know what might cause it? @ditkin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple little errors in your code. You should learn to use a debugger and to pay attention to warnings - Netbeans immediately gave one...

- `input = sc.next()+sc.nextLine();` not really an error but I cannot understand the why for this construct: you get one single token and immediately concatenate it with the end of line getting what a direct `nextLine` would have given - why not simply `input = sc.next();`?
- unwanted operator on stack:

  ```
     myStak.push((input));
     String operator = myStak.peek();
      switch(operator.charAt(0))
      {
          case '+':
          int a = Integer.parseInt(myStak.pop());
  ```

  when you execute `Integer.parseInt(myStak.pop())` the last token is... the operator which is likely to throw a ParseException! Either pop the operator first or even better do not push it...
- other operators are still not implemented...
- **never** use `==` to compare strings or objects but only `equals`. This line:

  ```
  while(input!= "+" || input!= "-" || input!= "*" || input!= "/");
  ```

  should be (both simpler and correct):

  ```
  while (! "+-*/".contains(input));
  ```

  this was immediately detected by Netbeans and I assume any IDE or Java compiler should issue a warning on it.

And a last remark, as you only use integers, 27/10 will be 2 not 2.7

Here is a cleaned up version of your code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();  <-- error?
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Stack myStak = new Stack(16);   // I broke at 3 at first test...
    System.out.println("Input : ");

    String input;
    while (true) {
        input = sc.next();    // let the Scanner deal with spaces and newlines
        String operator = input.substring(0, 1);
        if ("+-/*".contains(operator)) {  // is it an operator?
            int a = Integer.decode(myStak.pop()); // yes unpack and compute
            int b = Integer.decode(myStak.pop());
            int result = compute(a, b, operator);
            myStak.push(String.valueOf(result)); // push result back to stack and display
            System.out.println(a + " " + operator + " " + b + " = " + result);
        } else if ("=".equals(operator)) { // stop on =
            break;
        } else {
            myStak.push(input); // not an operator: assume a number and push it
        }
    }
}

// one single static function to avoid code duplication (DRY principle)
private static int compute(int i, int j, String op) {
    switch (op.charAt(0)) {
        case '+':
            return i + j;
        case '-':
            return i - j;
        case '*':
            return i * j;
        case '/':
            return i / j;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much , you taught me some fundamental things that i forgot to apply in my code. I did not know about "Integer.decode" so i will have to research about it. Your solution is very clear, thanks again for lending me a hand :) @Serge Ballesta